# Remove a certain field from a record if it satisfies certain conditions

Tags: awk

I want to use awk to do the following operations:

input:

```
0 foo foo dsag
1 foo foo dag
2 foo foo
3 asdg foo foo
4 foo gef foo
asgd 5 foo foo
```

output:

```
0 foo foo
1 foo foo
2 foo foo
3 foo foo
4 foo foo
5 foo foo
```

Basically, I parsed my data from pdf using OCR and there are some random stuff that comes in. So I need to remove these fields completely. I know the `condition` to test whether a field needs to be removed, but what's next?

I can only think of doing it using a for loop such as:

```
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) {
   if(condition holds) {
        printf("%s",$i);
   }
   print;
}
```

But is there a built-in function to do this?

**The nonsensical field does not occur in each row and does not occur at the same place.**

Comment: If you can post some actual data we can try and help.

Comment: Given that input, the best we can say is "if a field is not a number and is not the string "foo", remove it" -- I bet your real data is not that simple.

Comment: Basically, yes, if the fields you want to ignore are in unknown locations, you'll need to loop through each field and validate it. You could try to hack awk it by setting `RS` to `FS` and `ORS` to `FS` and using awk's built-in condition checking, but you'd need to come up with a rule to manually inserting real `ORS`…

Answer (score 0):

Using not one but two built in functions:

```
awk '{gsub(FS"[dag][[:alpha:]]*",""); sub("^""[dag][[:alpha:]]*"FS,"")}1' data
```

I think it's easiest to describe in an executable awk file with a function and comments.  Also with one extra condition added (`NF > 3`) to decide when to remove extra fields:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

function stripFieldsMatching( pattern ) {
    gsub( FS pattern, "" )    # remove all patterns in fields 2-NF
    sub( "^" pattern FS, "" ) # lastly, remove any leading pattern
}

NF > 3 {stripFieldsMatching( "[dag][[:alpha:]]*" )}
1
```

Obviously the pattern needs to be changed to match your data and you probably have more than 3 fields.  `gsub` and `sub` are operating on `$0` so every modified line can just be printed with the condition `1` at the end along with every unaltered line.